# Can't change user's session (switch users)

Tags: c++, windows

I'm working with C++.
I found in a multiple user profiles on computer, I want to write a service that change the session. but I can not change any session. I found in the following page code I'm using to change the user session.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379608(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I have tried CreateProcessAsUser function instead CreateProcessWithLogonW and CreateProcessWithTokenW. but it has all the functions returns FALSE. 
pi.hProcess and pi.hThread value from 0xcccccccc. The value returned error code 87.
The program ended here:

```
bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(
    hToken,            
    NULL,              
    NULL,           
    NULL,              
    NULL,             
    FALSE,             
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE , 
    NULL,              
    NULL,             
    &si,               
    &pi               
    );




RevertToSelf();

if (bResult && pi.hProcess != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}

if (pi.hThread != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){ //p.hTheread = 0xcccccccc
    wprintf(L"%d\n", GetLastError()); // ErrorCode=87. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread); 
}
```

When this code runs, I'm thinking of adding the code to the service.

Comment: It's been a while but doesn't impersonation require administrative privileges on windows?

Comment: Error 87 is `invalid parameter`. Show exactly how do you call the functions.

Comment: 0xcccccccc means hThread has never been assigned a value

Comment: I'm using it

if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken))
 {
  wprintf(L"OpenProcessToken()-Getting the handle to access token failed, error %u\n", GetLastError());
 }

Comment: Not checking *bResult* when you close the thread handle is of course a silly oversight.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean about bResult? Can you please explain a little more? @HansPassant

Comment: Change it to `if (bResult && pi.hThread != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)`  You already knew that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect the call to `CreateProcessAsUser` in the code you've posted to do?  You haven't given it a command line or specified a file to execute, so an `INVALID_PARAMETER` error is exactly what should happen.

Comment: you're right. thank you very much @HarryJohnston . I want to turn the user desktop. What should I do then. Which should I use api functions.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to bypass the logon screen, logging a user into the computer without them having to put in the username and password?

Comment: I want to switch to close the session and other sessions (log off A user desktop and log in B user desktop) @HarryJohnston

Comment: Two separate questions, then.  Logging off is `ExitWindowsEx` called in the context of the target session.  Logging on is a [credential provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or perhaps just [AutoAdminLogon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324737) (but [see this too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: Thank you very much @HarryJohnston . I will work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were misunderstanding the purpose of the CreateProcessAsUser function.  This is not an uncommon misunderstanding.

The Win32 functions CreateProcessAsUser, CreateProcessWithLogonW, LogonUser, LogonUserEx, LogonUserExExW, CreateLogonSession, and so on, are all concerned with the kernel's security model (processes, logon sessions and tokens) not with the interactive logon process (creating remote desktop sessions, associating them with a user, and switching between them).

There are no Win32 functions that allow you to control the interactive logon process, although there are functions (such as ExitWindowsEx) that allow you to log the current user off.

Instead, depending on your circumstances, you can register a [credential provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or use the [AutoAdminLogon registry settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324737).  The former is much more complicated; the latter is more limited - in particular, if the system is logged off, there does not appear to be any reliable way to initiate a logon with new credentials other that rebooting the system.

If you do use AutoAdminLogon, make sure you follow the instructions in [Protecting the Automatic Logon Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to keep the password (reasonably) secure.

Comment: I'm sorry to have kept you waiting. @HarryJohnston I noticed flaw with your help. Thank you very much.